# Named Credential - using a merge field

Tags: apex, callout, namedcredentials

Im facing issues trying to generate the auth header in Apex when using Named Credentials.

Unfortunately I cannot use the standard Named Credential approach (auto header generation) as I have to embed a session id in the header.

[image: Named Credential setup]

```
Blob authHeaderValue = Blob.valueOf('{!$Credential.Username}' + ':' + sessionId);
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setEndpoint('callout:endpointexample');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic' + ' ' +  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(authHeaderValue));
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(request);
```

If I hardcode the username it works fine so assuming {!$Credential.Username} is the issue here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Are you receiving any error message from the external service? If so, how does it look like?

Comment: Hi thanks. Just a 400 bad request error which isn't very useful.

Comment: What about testing it via curl, Postman or any other HTTP request tool? Does it work fine there?

Comment: the authentication in the named cred is set to Password Auth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named Credential acts as a runtime proxy. The proxy receives your HTTP request then searches its body or headers for the merge field as a *literal string*. If NC doesn't find the field, it won't interpolate (merge) it:

This works: `request.setHeader('X-Username', '{!$Credential.Username}');`

This also works (assuming *Generate Authorization Header* is unchecked):
`request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer: {!$Credential.Username}');`

This does not work:

```
Blob authHeaderValue = Blob.valueOf('{!$Credential.Username}' + ':' + sessionId);
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(authHeaderValue));
```

...nor does this:

```
Blob authHeaderValue = Blob.valueOf('{!$Credential.Username}');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(authHeaderValue));
```

...nor this:

```
Blob authHeaderValue = 
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('{!$Credential.Username}')));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use a merge field like this, because it's replaced when the call is made.

Effectively you're ending up with the encoded value of the literal text `{!$Credential.Username}:*sessionid*`.

It would be worth putting in a bit of logging to check this.

Comment: Upvoted your answer since it is essentially correct. One caveat: you didn't explain what `when the call is made` means and that's a critical element.