# Using username and password properties from named credentials to create an access token for x-authorization header

Tags: apex, callout, namedcredentials

I'm using named credentials to make a callout, I'm not using the `Generate Authorization Header` since the authorization uses an `x-authentication` header.

I have tried this:

```
    aeroplanCallout.setHeaderParameter('aux-username', '{!$Credential.UserName}');
    aeroplanCallout.setHeaderParameter('aux-password', '{!$Credential.Password}');

    String username = aeroplanCallout.getHeaderParameter('aux-username');
    String password = aeroplanCallout.getHeaderParameter('aux-password');

    String accessToken = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(username+':'+password));

    aeroplanCallout.setHeaderParameter('x-authorization', '{!$Credential.AuthorizationMethod} ' + accessToken);
```

I thought to get the values merged in those auxiliary headers and build the access token, set the actual header `x-authorization`, and then remove the auxiliary headers, but this didn't work.

I'm using a [framework](https://www.sfdcstop.com/2019/12/httpcalloutframework-light-weight.html) for the callouts, the framework works fine, but I'm not able to get the proper authorization.

I could set the access token as the named credential password, and use it, and it will work, but shouldn't I do by encoding the combination of username:password?

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Regardless, the values of merge fields are not available to your Apex code so your approach of deriving the token won't work: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377012/named-credential-using-a-merge-field . Stick to Apex without Named Credentials. Take a look at [Storing Sensitive Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_storing_sensitive_data.htm) for NC alternatives when dealing with credentials.

Comment: @identigral the authentication header (x-authentication) value is username:password combination. parsed as blob and encoded, I was trying to set the username and password in two auxiliary headers ( which will be deleted later), then get those values into a string for each one and do the encoding process... this callout has username and password. Will explore how to store the password data.