How do you correctly populate an External Credential from a Principal for a Named Credential?
In Salesforce, I want to consume a web API which I can successfully call from my command line like:
curl --location 'https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user?limit=10' \
--header 'app-id: SomeApiKey'

In Salesforce, I've created a named credential "Dummy_Api_Named_Credential" and set the External Credential to "Dummy Api External Credential" (API Name DummyApiExternalCredential).
If I simply create a Custom Header with Name "app-id" and Value "SomeApiKey", my Http works as expected.
However, then the Api Key, which I want to keep secret, ends up in the externalCredentials and potentially in my repository, which for obvious reasons, is very undesirable.  Nor is it desirable that anyone should need to manually create the externalCredentials on servers where the solution should be deployed, so we want to keep externalCredentials in the repo.
As I understand from documentation, what we should do is create a "Principal" on the External Credential, so I created "Dummy Api Principal" with Authentication Parameters Name "DummyApiClientKey" and Value "SomeApiKey" and then (jumping ahead a bit, after some debugging), created a Permission Set "Dummy_Api_Permissions" with External Credential Principal Access to "DummyApiExternalCredential - Dummy Api Principal".
Having created this Principal, I then tried updating my Custom Header's value from "SomeApiKey" to various things where I have tried to accesss the key from the Principal.  Attempts have included:

{!$DummyApiExternalCredential.DummyApiClientKey}
{!$Credential.DummyApiExternalCredential.DummyApiClientKey}
{! $DummyApiExternalCredential.DummyApiClientKey}
{! $Credential.DummyApiExternalCredential.DummyApiClientKey}
{!'' & $DummyApiExternalCredential.DummyApiClientKey}
{!'' & $Credential.DummyApiExternalCredential.DummyApiClientKey}
{! '' & $DummyApiExternalCredential.DummyApiClientKey}
{! '' & $Credential.DummyApiExternalCredential.DummyApiClientKey}

but all of these fail, even though returning to the simple, straight forward SomeApiKey will work as expected.
While attempting to debug, I've included
System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, '############ request app-id: ' + request.getHeader('app-id'));

In my Apex, but this does not seem to reveal anything as request.getHeader('app-id') is null regardless of how I set the value and regardless whether the request succeeds or fails (I guess this is either because Apex lacks access to this header and/or the header is not even populated until after the request leaves the Apex context).
In case it may help, here is the relevant metadata, or screenshots when that is not possible:
Dummy_Api_Named_Credential.namedCredential-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NamedCredential xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <allowMergeFieldsInBody>false</allowMergeFieldsInBody>
    <allowMergeFieldsInHeader>false</allowMergeFieldsInHeader>
    <calloutStatus>Enabled</calloutStatus>
    <generateAuthorizationHeader>true</generateAuthorizationHeader>
    <label>Dummy Api Named Credential</label>
    <namedCredentialParameters>
        <parameterName>Url</parameterName>
        <parameterType>Url</parameterType>
        <parameterValue>https://dummyapi.io</parameterValue>
    </namedCredentialParameters>
    <namedCredentialParameters>
        <externalCredential>DummyApiExternalCredential</externalCredential>
        <parameterName>ExternalCredential</parameterName>
        <parameterType>Authentication</parameterType>
    </namedCredentialParameters>
    <namedCredentialType>SecuredEndpoint</namedCredentialType>
</NamedCredential>

DummyApiExternalCredential.externalCredential-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExternalCredential xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <authenticationProtocol>Custom</authenticationProtocol>
    <externalCredentialParameters>
        <parameterGroup>Dummy Api Principal</parameterGroup>
        <parameterName>Dummy Api Principal</parameterName>
        <parameterType>NamedPrincipal</parameterType>
        <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
    </externalCredentialParameters>
    <externalCredentialParameters>
        <parameterGroup>DefaultGroup</parameterGroup>
        <parameterName>app-id</parameterName>
        <parameterType>AuthHeader</parameterType>
        <parameterValue>{!$Credential.DummyApiExternalCredential.DummyApiClientKey}</parameterValue>
        <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
    </externalCredentialParameters>
    <label>Dummy Api External Credential</label>
</ExternalCredential>

Dummy Api Principal Screenshot

Dummy_Api_Permissions.permissionset-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <externalCredentialPrincipalAccesses>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <externalCredentialPrincipal>DummyApiExternalCredential-Dummy Api Principal</externalCredentialPrincipal>
    </externalCredentialPrincipalAccesses>
    <hasActivationRequired>false</hasActivationRequired>
    <label>Dummy Api Permissions</label>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>UserExternalCredential</object>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
</PermissionSet>

UserExternalCredential.object-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <externalCredentialPrincipalAccesses>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <externalCredentialPrincipal>DummyApiExternalCredential-Dummy Api Principal</externalCredentialPrincipal>
    </externalCredentialPrincipalAccesses>
    <hasActivationRequired>false</hasActivationRequired>
    <label>Dummy Api Permissions</label>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>UserExternalCredential</object>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
</PermissionSet>

So, how do I correctly set the Custom Header from the Principal?  Am I misunderstanding something?  Is there a better way I should solve this problem (which might not even involve the Principal)?

Does this answer your question? External Credential's 'Principal' not allowing multiple parameters

@identigral, Thanks for the response.  I don't think it does since I only have the one parameter and no matter how many times I've filled the value and resaved it, I've never seen any signs that it worked.... I can try again, but it would be good to know the correct value to put in the Header so we can eliminate that as the point of failure.

The referenced answer shows exactly that. The format is {!$Credential.<API Name of External Cred>.<Name of the API key param>}'

...plus there's https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_and_api_keys.htm&type=5

@identigral, Yeah, I saw this as well... which is why I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.   :-/

... If it helps, I updated my question to include metadata and screenshots.

You can't extract the interpolated (merged) values until the request left the building: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377012/named-credential-using-a-merge-field

@identigral, I've suspected that's why System.debug isn't helpful... but it still doesn't tell me what is going wrong.  :-(

For the formulas to work would need to navigate to your Named Credential and enable Allow Formulas in HTTP Header, Allow Formulas in HTTP Body.
This allows you to use the merge field syntax - {!$Credential.externalCredentialName.principalAuthenticationParameterName}
Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_and_api_keys.htm&language=en_US&type=5#nc_custom_headers_and_api_keys



However, then the Api Key, which I want to keep secret, ends up in the externalCredentials and potentially in my repository, which for obvious reasons, is very undesirable. Nor is it desirable that anyone should need to manually create the externalCredentials on servers where the solution should be deployed, so we want to keep externalCredentials in the repo.

Salesforce currently doesn't support deploying Principal Authentication Parameters which is a bummer and would need to be a post deployment step.

Actually only need to enable the header for this use case, but yes, this works!  :-)
